# @font-face problem in SharePoint

Tags: css, branding

I'm trying to host my own font for my Site Collection, by using @font-face. I believe I've followed all best practices for the declaration:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'ciclefina_italic';
src: url('cicle_fina_italic-webfont.eot');
src: url('cicle_fina_italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('cicle_fina_italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('cicle_fina_italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('cicle_fina_italic-webfont.svg#ciclefina_italic') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

This works for Firefox/Chrome, but Internet Explorer 7/8/9 is running into an error:

> CSS3111: @font-face encountered unknown error. 
>   cicle_fina_italic_webfont.eot

I've tried adding mime types to my web.config file but no joy. Has anyone else run into this or had more luck hosting their own font on their SharePoint site?

Comment: Is it this maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065362/ie9-blocks-download-of-cross-origin-web-font

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? we are also facing same issue

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember this was so long ago. Embedding the font data might be a promising solution - https://medium.com/@tbarkow/data-uris-and-font-face-2c1de247c94e